# Как правильно использовать iframe под задачу?

Tags: html, iframe

Есть сайт№1(мой) и есть сайт№2(не мой).

Пример содержания первого сайта:

```
<div class="header"><a href="/сайт№2">Личный кабинет</a></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Пример содержания второго сайта (в код которого у меня нет доступа):

```
<div class="logo"></div>
<div class="form"></div>
```

Суть: Нужно при нажатие на ссылку "Личный кабинет" открыть сайт№2 удалив при этом из него `class="logo"`

Как я это вижу:

1. Нажимаем "Личный кабинет"
2. Открывается маленькое окно (blank?) с `<div class="form">` (iframe?)

Как вообще это реализовать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Вот идея. В iframe же можно скрыть скролл. Можно ли с помощью JS остановить скролл iframe в нужном месте, и потом скрыть его?

Answer (score 2):

Вот примерное решение которое требовалось:

```css
#outerdiv 
{ 
width:756px; 
height:496px; 
overflow:hidden; 
position:relative; 
}

#innerIframe 
{ 
position:absolute; 
top:-546px; 
left:-349px; 
width:1280px; 
height:1200px; 
}
```

```html
<div id='outerdiv'> 
<iframe src="http://www.intellicast.com/National/Radar/Current.aspx?location=USNY0850&animate=true" id='innerIframe' scrolling=no></iframe> 
</div>
```

Но не окончательное. Потому что в моем случае будет форма логина и пароля которая должна выбрасывать из iframe на новую вкладку, а не оставаться в окне.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете открыть другой сайт в iframe. Но вы не можете влиять на стили и DOM сайта в iframe. Запрет введен в целях безопасности, в частности для борьбы с фишингом.

То есть, если доступа к коду сайта №2 у вас нет, то ничего изменить в нем вы не сможете - только открыть в новой вкладке или в iframe.

Раскрою идею из комментариев - проскроллить документ в iframe до какого-то места и затем скрыть скролл. Проскроллить действительно можно, вот таким кодом в js:

```
var myIframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
myIframe.onload = function () {
    myIframe.contentWindow.scrollTo(xcoord,ycoord);
}
```

Но это возможно только в том случае, если страница №2 внутри iframe находится на том же домене, что и ваша страница №1. Если же внутри iframe открывается страница другого сайта, браузер не позволит вам влиять на нее каким-либо образом через js - это еще один запрет в целях безопасности.

Comment: Это само собой разумеется. Просто может быть с помощью JS на стороне клиента можно вырезать класс? JS и iframe с сайтом№2 будет на сайте№1 же. Очень нужен любой костыль.

Comment: Вот идея. В iframe же можно скрыть скролл. Можно ли с помощью JS остановить скролл iframe в нужном месте, и потом скрыть его?

Comment: Вы можете так сделать. Но только если обе страницы находятся на одном и том же домене. В вашем случае, как я понимаю, это не так, поэтому попытка проскроллить, или каким-то иным способом повлиять на документ в iframe, вызовет ошибку доступа к чужому домену через js.

Comment: Решил вопрос обычным CSS. Выхватил нужную часть, и запретил скролл.

Comment: Сможете поделиться решением? Через какое-то время вам станет доступна возможность ответа на собственный вопрос, опишете там ваше решение?

Comment: Да, конечно. Единственная проблема которую видимо не решить, это чтобы после ввода в форме логина/пароля выбрасывало на чистую страницу. А весь сайт остается в этом фрейме =(